# How to rotate the whole viewport with map in it?

Tags: javascript, web, mapbox-gl-js

I'm making a web application for a touch screen that requires a 'rotate screen' functionality. It's easy to rotate everything using CSS transform, and it works on most pages. The problem is when there's a plugin like Mapbox that uses mouse events, the events' position are still relative to the view port. For example, after I rotate `<body>` 180 degrees, and click top left of the map, which is bottom right of the browser, mapbox would think I clicked bottom right of the map. Same with dragging, it just moved the map the opposite direction.

Is there a better way to rotate a whole page, including all the mouse events? Or is there a way to work around it like automatically replacing mouse event coordinates based on rotation?

Comment: if it's for mobile then your best bet is probably to try to rotate the webview itself.. as in, rotate the actual browser window that way everything stays relative.

Comment: No it's not mobile. It's a giant Windows touch screen.

Comment: There maybe a possibility that the issue is with mapbox library. Have to check it. Try the same thing with leaftlet.js (http://leafletjs.com/) or openlayers(http://openlayers.org/). Hope you will not face issues.

Comment: Had a quick test in the console on the examples on their websites. All have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend rotating web view itself, as suggested by Pamblam above. GL JS (like most Javascript libraries) is not designed to map inputs to account for CSS transforms.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up putting the whole app in an iframe so I can rotate it in the browser.